# How do I check if an element is present on a webpage?

Tags: selenium

I'm using BrowserFactory in selenium and not WebDriver. I would like to check if an element is present on the DOM. If yes click it, otherwise do something else. There should be a simple solution to it but I'm not using WebDriver. If I do use it, it opens a new browser window and does everything in that.

Comment: Please click on edit and paste your code into the question. If it looks like you haven't tried anything people will downvote your question and you may not get an answer.

Comment: **`using BrowserFactory in selenium and not WebDriver`** Can you showcase your code trials please?

Comment: Welcome to stack! What is `BrowserFactory`? I've seen a few implementations of a browser factory which usually just serves up a driver instance based on the browser you choose. From your question it sounds like your `BrowserFactory` is doing something different. Please share some code examples for what you're trying to do and where it's going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this method to verify if the element is present

```
public static void isElementPresent(WebElement element) {
    //log.info("Checking if element is present");
    if(element.isDisplayed();){
    element.click();
     }  

}
```

Comment: If `element` is not present, `element.isDisplayed()` will throw a `NullPointerException`!

Comment: you can surrounded by a try catch statement

Comment: I find another way which is a rather "hacky" way.

`@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = ".button")
    private List<WebElement> goToPrograms;`

then access the item using 
`goToPrograms.get(0).click();`
Also check for indexoutofrange exception in case the element is not present